# Single fetch request with input event listener and on page load

Tags: javascript, fetch

I would like to use a single fetch request when the page is loaded and when some text is put in the input field. For example, there is page A with an input field, the user will type something and then will be redirected to page B where fetch request will be called immediately and results will be returned. Then, when the user is on page B and if wants to change search criteria I would like to create a new fetch request and get data back. I'm able to get data back but then if the user clicks on result console log is fired twice instead of once. Any idea how to overcome this?
thanks

Here is my setup.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>

        <input type="text" name="search" value=1 id="search">
        <button type="button" name="button" id="startSearch">Search</button>
        <table id="results"></table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      let searchString = document.getElementById('search')
      let resultDiv = document.getElementById('results')

        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+searchString.value)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => {
            resultDiv.innerHTML = ''
            let tr = document.createElement('tr')
            let td = document.createElement('td')
            let text = document.createTextNode(json.name)
            td.appendChild(text)
            tr.appendChild(td)
            resultDiv.appendChild(tr)
          })

        resultDiv.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
          console.log('click1')
          console.log(e.target.innerText)
        })

    </script>
      </body>
    </html>

what I have also tried is this 

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>

        <input type="text" name="search" value=1 id="search">
        <button type="button" name="button" id="startSearch">Search</button>
        <table id="results"></table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      let searchString = document.getElementById('search')
      let resultDiv = document.getElementById('results')

        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+searchString.value)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => {
            resultDiv.innerHTML = ''
            let tr = document.createElement('tr')
            let td = document.createElement('td')
            let text = document.createTextNode(json.name)
            td.appendChild(text)
            tr.appendChild(td)
            resultDiv.appendChild(tr)
          })

        resultDiv.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
          console.log(e.target)
        })

    searchString.addEventListener('input', (e) => {

          fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+searchString.value)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
              resultDiv.innerHTML = ''
              let tr = document.createElement('tr')
              let td = document.createElement('td')
              let text = document.createTextNode(json.name)
              td.appendChild(text)
              tr.appendChild(td)
              resultDiv.appendChild(tr)
              })
        })

        resultDiv.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            console.log(e.target)
          })

        </script>
          </body>
        </html>
```

but then when I click on `td` element I get it twice, and it is clear to me why. So, my question is can I have somehow single fetch request which is working on page load and on the input event listener

Comment: If you run second example you will see that it is not working as expected, because if you click on result console log will be fired twice and I need it only once.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not fire the console.log event twice, it's fired only once, as expected.

1. Open jsfiddle.net
2. Paste your code in the html panel
3. Open the browser console
4. Run the code
5. Click the search result
6. console.log is fired only once

Comment: here is the fiddle so anyone can check console.log https://jsfiddle.net/lemonandsoda/amhsvxf1/1/

Comment: The code in your fiddle is not the same of the code in your post.
The problem with the code in your fiddle is it contains two times "resultDiv.addEventListener('click', (e) => { console.log(e.target) })", so 2 listeners are attached. So when you click, you will get 2 functions called. The fiddle I came up with your post is: https://jsfiddle.net/0pf4dob6/ and when clicking the row, it's fired only once.

Comment: I have provided 2 examples, in first one, and this is the one you took you are getting result because input field has default value, if you try to put any other number in input field nothing will happened because there is no event listener. In second approach (fiddle I have provided) there is an event listener but you saw then console log is fired twice. I'm fully aware of the reason. My question is, is it possible to have single fetch request which is working on page load and on input event listener or what should I change in second example so I get console log only once